# why function' object has no attribute 'user' showing up?

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-middleware

I tried to create 2 users in my project.

> models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type_choices = ((1, "Admin"), (2, "NotesUser"))
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=user_type_choices, default=1)

class Admin(models.Model):
    user_id = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class NotesUser(models.Model):
    user_id = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def create_user_profile(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.user_type == 1:
            Admin.objects.create(user_id=instance)
        if instance.user_type == 2:
            NotesUser.objects.create(user_id=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.user_type == 1:
        instance.admin.save()
    if instance.user_type == 2:
        instance.notesuser.save()
```

and i wrote this middleware for checking user access

> LoginCheckMiddleWare.py

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse

class LoginCheckMiddleWare(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_view(self, view_func, request, view_args, view_kwargs):
        modulename=view_func.__module__
        user = request.user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            if user.user_type == "1":
                if modulename == "todo_app.views" or modulename == "todo_app.AdminViews":
                    pass
                else:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("admin_home"))
            elif user.user_type == "2":
                if modulename == "todo_app.UserViews" or modulename == "todo_app.views":
                    pass
                else:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("user_home"))
            else:
                pass
                #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("log_in"))
        else:
            if request.path == reverse("log_in") or request.path == reverse("login_save") or modulename == "django.contrib.auth.views" or modulename == "todo_app.views":
                pass
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("log_in"))
```

I mentioned the middleware I created in app into settings.py file.

> settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'todo_app.LoginCheckMiddleWare.LoginCheckMiddleWare',

]
```

But an error is showing when I tried to access my login page.

```
'function' object has no attribute 'user'
```

[image: this is the error what's showing]

can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/middleware/#process-view) the first parameter to the process view is the request object please change the function as below:

```py
def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs)
```

Comment: thanks man it worked the previous order was the issue